# Generating text by selecting Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created something like a survey, I have a bunch of questions with yes or no answers, (every couple has the same name property).

I need to insert text string into textarea if the user chooses "Yes", and replace that text with something else if he clicked "No"... etc till the end of the questions.

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: none;" class="s_node" id="child_of_option_1_node_16">
  <p>
    <input id="option_2" name="plan" value="Choice 1 text string..." type="radio">
    <label id="option_2" for="option_2">Solved</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="option_3" name="plan" value="Choice 2 text string..." type="radio">
    <label id="option_3" for="option_3">Not-Solved</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#option_1').is(':checked')) {
      $('#child_of_option_1_node_16').show('fast');
    } else if (!$('#option_1').is(':checked')) {
      $('#child_of_option_1_node_16').hide('fast');
      clearradios(child_of_option_1_node_16);
    }
    $('#option_1').parent().bind('click', function() {
      if ($('#option_1').is(':checked')) {
        $('#child_of_option_1_node_16').show('fast');

        document.GenerationForm.myTextArea.value += document.getElementById("CstName").value + ",,,";

      } else if (!$('#option_1').is(':checked')) {
        clearradios(child_of_option_1_node_16);
        hidechildren(child_of_option_1_node_16);
        $('#child_of_option_1_node_16').hide('fast');

      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: So you need to take the attr value of the input and add it to a textarea ?

Comment: that's exactly what I need to do :)

Comment: Check the answer I post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work

```
<div style="display: none;" class="s_node" id="child_of_option_1_node_16">
  <p>
    <input id="option_2" onclick="changeText(this)" name="plan" value="Yes" type="radio">
    <label id="option_2" for="option_2">Solved</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="option_3"  onclick="changeText(this)" name="plan" value="No" type="radio">
    <label id="option_3" for="option_3">Not-Solved</label>
  </p>
```

```
<script>
function changeText(e){
   var value = e.value;
   var textbox = document.getElementById("yourTextBoxId");

   textbox.value = value;
}
</scrip>
```

Just a thought...

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! many thanks Pieter :) .. I've edited it a little bit to apply on multiple questions without removing the previous answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is saving the values on an `array` and then set it to the `textarea` element:

```js
var ans = [];

$('.s_node').on('change','input',function(){
  var par = $(this).parents('.s_node'),
      valu = par.find(':checked').val();
  ans[par.index()-1] = valu;
  $('#mytextarea').val(ans.join("\n"))
})
```

```css
.s_node {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
textarea {
  width:80%;
  min-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s_node">
  <p>
    <input id="option_2" name="plan" value="Choice for plan Solved..." type="radio">
    <label for="option_2">Solved</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="option_3" name="plan" value="Choice for plan text string..." type="radio">
    <label for="option_3">Not-Solved</label>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="s_node">
  <p>
    <input id="option_4" name="flight" value="Choice for FLIGHT Solved..." type="radio">
    <label for="option_4">Solved</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="option_5" name="flight" value="Choice for FLIGHT text string..." type="radio">
    <label for="option_5">Not-Solved</label>
  </p>
</div>
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: That worked also, thanks Dani for the effort writing this code.

Comment: Np mate glad to help U @MohamedHussien, hope this helps reduce the lines of code